# How to create a List collection staring data in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I was given a task to create an implementation of generic collection basing on simple array. Collection should implement List interface. Currently I have:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}

class MyCollection<T> implements List<T>{
    T[] tab;

    MyCollection() {
        this.tab = (T[])new Object[10];
    }

    public List subList(int from, int to){
        return new ArrayList();
    }

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] t){}
    public T[] toArray(){}
    public ListIterator listIterator(){}
    public ListIterator listIterator(int i){}
    public Iterator iterator(){}
    public boolean contains(){}
    public boolean contains(Object o){}
    public boolean isEmpty(){}
    public int size(){}
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o){}
    public int indexOf(Object o){}
    public T remove(int i){}
    public boolean remove(Object o){}
    public void clear(){}
    public void add(int i, T t){}
    public boolean add(T t){}
    public T set(int i, T t ){}
    public T get(int i){}
    public boolean retainAll(Collection c){}
    public boolean removeAll(Collection c){}
    public boolean addAll(int i, Collection c){}
    public boolean addAll(Collection c){}
    public boolean containsAll(Collection c){}
}
```

How can I implement the required methods if my data is stored in an array? How for example I can write listIterator for an array?

Comment: you've started good with circles. now that's the time to draw the rest of owl! http://theord.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/drawOwl.png

Comment: Is this homework?  If not, the answer is `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check out the **java.util.ArrayList** source code for some implementation patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the easy methods (e.g. `get` and `set`). Then move on to the harder ones and see if you can implement any of them in terms of the easier ones. If you get stuck, move on to a different method - it might give you some ideas about the one you're stuck on.

Iterators will probably be the trickiest, so maybe leave them until last. Hint: The iterators will probably need to be inner classes; to know where they are in the list; and have a reference back to the array.